# Declare table variable in sqldatasource (aspnet)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sqldatasource

I have a query that I try in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, and this query work fine:

```
DECLARE @tableVariable TABLE (fecha DATE, valor Float);
INSERT @tableVariable SELECT fecha, valor FROM table1;
SELECT * FROM @tableVariable
```

When I go to VisualStudio and paste this query in sqldatasource, not work.

Anybody can help me?

Thanks

**SOLVED**

Finally, the problem is solved remove the tag `<SelectParameters> <asp:Parameter Name = "tableVariable" /> </SelectParameters>` into sqldatasource.

Thanks to all!

Comment: why don't you just paste `SELECT fecha, valor FROM table1` in SqlDataSource? I don't think it supports multiple SQL statements.

Comment: The real query is very long for put here, and very complex. It is an abbreviated example. Must be some way to be able to run in asp.net. I use sqldatasource for show the result in a GridView.

Comment: When I put this in my sqldatasource for it is asking me to Define Parameters, and @tableVariable is not a parameter in my application, but a temp table in sql statement.

Comment: in this case, just encapsulate the complex query in a stored procedure and use that in the data source

Comment: How i can encapsulate the complex query? Any example? Thanks!

Comment: why don't you use store procedure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating a [stored procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx), like so:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ComplexQuery
as
    DECLARE @tableVariable TABLE (fecha DATE, valor Float);
    INSERT @tableVariable SELECT fecha, valor FROM table1;

    -- more complex logic in here

    SELECT * FROM @tableVariable

go
```

Then, in your data source specify the name of the procedure.

Example:

```xml
        <asp:SqlDataSource
            id="SqlDataSource1"
            runat="server"
            ConnectionString="..."
            SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"                
            SelectCommand="ComplexQuery">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Can I pass arguments (parameters) to a stored procedure? It is possible drop and insert rows dynamically? When I call to ComplexQuery, I need pass arguments o parameters.

Comment: @user2024475 sure, see the stored procedure link I posted for details on how to add parameters to a stored proc. Then, specify the parameters in the data source as explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z72eefad(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Oh Thanks you very much! This is the best answer for my problem. I haven't got reputation and I can't click to "answer useful". Thanks you very much again!

Answer (score 1):

Is it not worth just converting the the declared table to a temp table i.e.

```
CREATE TABLE #tableVariable (fecha DATE, valor Float)
```

You would need a DROP TABLE #tableVariable later to make sure you are cleaning memory but it will have the desired affect I believe.

Comment: This option is computationally heavier, no?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be putting a long and complex query into SqlDataSource - that's really for binding a table or view to a datagrid without having to mess around in code behind. If you want to run a complex query you should either set up a stored procedure to do it and call that from SqlCommand, or put the text for the query into SqlCommand. Either way I don't think SqlDataSource is the way to go here.

Comment: I don't need a Stored Procedure. If I put the text of query into SqlCommand, I can use a GridView for show the result?

Comment: All the SqlCommand is going to do is run a SQL statement against the database. If the statement is going to return some data (SELECT * FROM...) then you still need to get the results of that into something that you can bind to a GridView like a DataSet or DataTable. Maybe SqlDataAdapter is the way to go here - you can feed it some SQL and easily generate a DataSet from it.